# What is the ⌥ key?

Tags: keyboard

Is this key the same as shift?

If so, why don't people just call it shift? I spent a long time looking around for what this key means. Google returned no results. My MacBook Air keyboard does not have this symbol either.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is the [Option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_key) key (
<kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows).

It's not the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd> - it's generally used as a secondary [*modifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key) for keyboard shortcuts ([Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key) <kbd>⌘</kbd> being the primary modifier) and for shortcuts that don't perform an action (e.g. Option-8 is a bullet point `•` and Option-Shift-8 is a degree symbol `°`).

---

From the official "macOS User Guide":

- [What are those symbols shown in menus on Mac?](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-are-those-symbols-shown-in-menus-cpmh0011/mac)
- [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

Comment: It is indeed interesting to note that that symbol isn't used on some keyboard layouts, like those of a MBA. Instead it has `option` written out in full.

Comment: @Gerry (New) US keyboards don't use the symbols as much as new European ones or older keyboards.

Comment: But even if you have a US keyboard, with "option" written out, you will see menu shortcuts with that funny symbol in them...  Same for "shift" and "control".

Answer (score 5):

The first symbol is the [option key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_key), located between the command and control keys on a typical Mac keyboard.

[image]